# List flattening

Tags: python, list

```
def flatten_lists(nested):
    '''
    >>> flatten_lists([[0], [1, 2], 3])
    [0, 1, 2, 3]
    '''
    list_of_lists = ([[0], [1, 2], 3])
    List_flat =  []
    for i in range(len(list_of_lists)): 
      for j in range (len(list_of_lists[i])): 
        List_flat.append(list_of_lists[i][j]) 
    return List_flat
```

I want to flatten the list `[[0], [1, 2], 3]` but I'm getting error:

```
TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()
```

how to solve this

Comment: the last element, `3`, is not wrapped in a list constructor so when `i` is the last element, you're trying to take the length on a single integer, which is meaningless. Seems like you need to come up with some logic to test for whether a `len` exists

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to treat every element of the outer list as though it is a list. The problem is that some elements in the inner list are not lists. A simple fix for your code in particular would be to wrap the inner `for` loop in a `try`/`except` block:

```
for i in range(len(list_of_lists)): 
    try:  # if the element is a list then add it
        for j in range (len(list_of_lists[i])): 
            List_flat.append(list_of_lists[i][j]) 
    except TypeError:  # so, if iteration fails, the element isn't a list
        List_Flat.append(list_of_lists[i])
```

Comment: The best way in python is what I'm doing here - try to iterate through it, and if it fails then it's not a sublist. Technically you could also check if the element has the necessary constructs for iteration (namely, an `__iter__()` method), but that's both confusing and can fail with custom datatypes.